# Neo4j Return Affected Nodes in an Update Query Statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jphp

Running this Cypher Query:

```
MATCH (n:`User`) WHERE type = 'artist' SET n.updated_at = '2014-05-06 21:32:00', n.name = 'example' RETURN count(n)
```

This will return the number of matched nodes regardless of them being affected by the `SET` statement or not.

Is there a way to return only the number of affected nodes ?

Comment: I cannot replicate this behavior.  When I run similar queries, the count returned is the count of updated records.  In fact it should be this way, because "n" is not just what is in the MATCH clause, it's filtered by what's in WHERE.   What number do you get back from this query?

Comment: You might also want to add version info, and give concretes on what your {parameters} are.

Comment: Just updated the question's query to be a bit clearer. Thing is this will return the count of the nodes matched by the WHERE clause, what should be returned is, in case the 'updated_at' and 'name' properties were not changed the node should not be considered "affected". Say the query matches 10 nodes, 3 of them already have the 'updated_at' and 'name' the same values that are being SET here, so the affected nodes will be 7 not 10. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: The SET will ONLY operate on ALL those nodes returned by the filtered MATCH query, i.e. what @FrobberOfBits says is the way it is.  It is a "forced" SET.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want to get a count of modified nodes then you need to include the negation of the `SET` clause as a `WHERE` clause for the `MATCH`. That way you will only match nodes that need to be updated (and can therefore return a count of them).